# Sending dates as values across php pages in form submissions

Tags: php, forms, date, request

I have a form submission in PHP that posts to MYSQL. But before the form is completed it diverts to another page to complete. So on the first page date and time are selected, this then directs to a page where name, email and other details are entered, on submission from this page all of the information is entered into the database and the window redirects to another page.

I am having difficulty calling and displaying the correct information regarding the dates.

The date and time page submits:

```
     $origDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $datesA[$i]['date']);
     $formatdate = $origDateTime->format('D, F d, Y');
echo "<option value='" . $datesA[$i]['dateid'] . "'>" . $formatdate . "</option>";
```

The above is my work around of how to have usable data. ['date'] didn't work as a value field when I needed to have a reference to query the database to populate a second option list for the available times, I believe this was because it was not able to compare the strings, I created ['dateid'] which is an integer, as a workable solution.

Now when I go to the second page, where further details are submitted, I need to display the chosen date, and be able to isolate the month so I can access the correct months database, as they are labeled by month.

All of this would work fine, but ['dateid'] is not converting correctly to a date, as it is only three figures, 219 would be February 19, it is reading as September, but I see now that three digits would never work regardless.

I have tried zerofill to make a 4 digit dateid. I also tried accessing the variable $formatdate, which has all the correct information, but I don't know how to send that variable to the second page.

Thee request code for the second page where further information is added to the form:

```
<?php
$sdate = $_REQUEST['sdate'];
$stime = $_REQUEST['stime'];
$convMon = DateTime::createFromFormat('nj', $sdate);
$thismonth = $convMon->format('F, d');
$month = strtolower($thismonth);
$formdate = $_REQUEST[$formdate];

include 'connect.php';

$sql = mysqli_query($datab, "SELECT * FROM $month WHERE $sdate = dateid")
```

Comment: Can you rephrase this? It is very hard to follow what your question is. You are open to SQL injections, and a table for each month seems like a bad schema.

Comment: @user3783243 Ah sorry it's not clear, I actually just discovered I can use SESSION to transfer the data. But I was concerned I had other problems than what I was originally asking. What can I do about SQL injections? And why would you say separate months are a bad idea? I did it that way as I need to add more options to each date, and once the month has passed I don't need the table any more. Each month is used to build a calendar.

Comment: Parameterize your query and use prepared statements to avoid SQL injections. You could just have it be `table` in that can and `truncate` it at the end (or start) of every month. I see no reason to have it be dynamic. If you need it to be dynamic it should likely be an indexed column inside itself, then it can be limited by that `WHERE $sdate = dateid and month=?`

Comment: You capture date and time on the first page.  I would not process them at all in that first page and just send the captured text value to the second page.  I would then process the date and time text in that second page.  Passing text between pages is trivial through your `<form>`.